# How do higher levels of the Hoarder trait work?

Tags: coromon

The Official Wiki's article on the [Hoarder](https://coromon.wiki.gg/wiki/Hoarder) trait gives the table of chance for each item by level.

But doesn't say anything about how improved Hoarder levels changes the loot table or chances.

So, what do improved Hoarder levels do?